# WinPcap doesn't get adapters' name properly

Tags: c++, interface, adapter, pcap, winpcap

This is my adapters list using ipconfig /all to check:

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DESKTOP-QFRLS7U
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 44-A8-42-E9-AD-9E
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 1:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 5E-BB-58-80-40-93
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 12:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 1E-BB-58-80-40-93
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Dell Wireless 1707 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 4C-BB-58-80-40-93
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::35b0:e8c7:d77a:6bc2%11(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.104(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, February 1, 2018 11:17:02 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, February 2, 2018 1:33:13 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 189578072
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-B9-5B-B1-44-A8-42-E9-AD-9E
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:408:c3a0:84e7:3193(Preferred)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::408:c3a0:84e7:3193%13(Preferred)
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 167772160
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-B9-5B-B1-44-A8-42-E9-AD-9E
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Disabled
```

And here is my adapters' list using winpcap to check:

```
1: \Device\NPF_{00F95F1B-F023-4834-836C-7581C882A33D}: Microsoft
    ip ipv6: fe80::35c9:e7b8:bba5:841c

2: \Device\NPF_{1E4A6514-33EF-42E4-AD5E-068B20583040}: Microsoft
    ip ipv6: fe80::bce9:3ff3:2350:f858

3: \Device\NPF_{A5A9536E-E0B3-42B9-987D-35F76E05324F}: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
    ip ipv6: fe80::31af:462c:7c70:835e
    ip ipv4: 192.168.0.101

4: \Device\NPF_{442AFF8C-1D12-41E0-B549-4EC8E3773363}: Microsoft
    ip ipv6: fe80::35b0:e8c7:d77a:6bc2
    ip ipv4: 192.168.0.104
```

(names get from pcap_if_t->description)

There are some mismatches between the two but i can't determine what caused this after seaching many forums. I really need these names to be correct in order to get the device precisely to capture packets.

Comment: Did you retrieve the two lists at the same moment (while being connected to the same networks)? In `ipconfig /all`, it looks like you're not connected to any network.

Comment: I did get these two lists at the same time, and arcording to list 1, i'm connecting to `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` imo.